# Reverse cascade rule doesn't effects to overriden delete method of mongoengine object

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have two document objects (`Job` and `JobLog`) and one has reference to another one (JobLog has reference field to Job). And reference is defined with `reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE`.

```
# Job class
class Job(db.Document):
    (fields)

class JobLog(db.Document):
    (fields)
    job = ReferenceField(Job, required=True, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
```

When I delete the `Job` object and referenced `JobLog` deleted safely.

```
>>> job = Job()
>>> job.save()
>>> job_log = JobLog()
>>> job_log = job
>>> job_log.save()
>>> job.delete()

>>> JobLog.objects().all()
[]
```

After a while I I override the `delete` method of `JobLog` like this:

```
class JobLog(db.Document):
    (fields)
    job = ReferenceField(Job, required=True, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)

    def delete(self, signal_kwargs=None, **write_concern):
        (some operations)
        print("Delete method called.")
        super(JobLog, self).delete(signal_kwargs, **write_concern)
```

But while deleting the `Job` overriden delete method did not call.

```
>>> job = Job()
>>> job.save()
>>> job_log = JobLog()
>>> job_log = job
>>> job_log.save()
>>> job.delete()

>>> JobLog.objects().all()
[]
```

Referenced `JobLog` deleted but did not call the overriden `delete` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a solution and I am sharing it for if anyone faced with this kind of issue.

I don't know the every details why the overriden `delete` method not called but it seems the base `Document` class saw the inherited class as an `Document` class and calls it's super class method. So the overriden delete method not called.

The solution is using [signals](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html) to ensure operations handled before or after methods like delete and save. This snippet worked for me:

```
class JobLog(db.Document):

    @classmethod
    def pre_delete(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        (pre delete operations)

from mongoengine import signals
signals.pre_delete.connect(JobLog.pre_delete, sender=JobLog)
```

The signal support is provided by [blinker](https://pypi.org/project/blinker/) library. Make sure installed before using signals of mongoengine.